# Remember page state on navigation back

Tags: jquery, click

I have 3 `DIV`s which show up on click. At any time only one DIV is visible (the other DIVs hide).

The problem is, `#div1` has hyperlinks to other subpages. After coming back from such subpage (by clicking the browser's "Back" button) `#div1` disappears, the scroll position is where its supposed to be, but the `#div1` is hidden. How to make that the browser could remember this DIV state and position after coming *back* from a subpage?

```
$(function () {
    $('#showdiv1').click(function () {
        $('div[id^=div]').hide();
        $('#div1').show();
    });
    $('#showdiv2').click(function () {
        $('div[id^=div]').hide();
        $('#div2').show();
    });
    $('#showdiv3').click(function () {
        $('div[id^=div]').hide();
        $('#div3').show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Using location.hash

One way to do it would be to exploit what browsers already provide: anchors with a hash `href`, `window.location.hash` and the CSS `:target` selector

Having this HTML

```
<style>
    [id^="div"] {
        display: none;
    }
    [id^="div"]:target {
        display: block;
    }
</style>

<a href="#div1">div1</a>
<a href="#div2">div2</a>
<a href="#div3">div3</a>

<div id="div1">div1 <a href="//google.com">Google</a></div>
<div id="div2">div2 <a href="//stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a></div>
<div id="div3">div3 <a href="//developer.mozilla.org">MDN</a></div>
```

all we need is just a bit of JavaScript to set a default hash if none exists

```
if(!location.hash) location.hash = "div1";
```

## Using the History API - pushState

To *remember* a state when a user navigates back to your page - a useful method to use is the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) and retrieve custom data from the `state` object.

Given this HTML:

```
<style>
    .none {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<button type="button" data-show="#div1">div1</button>
<button type="button" data-show="#div2">div2</button>
<button type="button" data-show="#div3">div3</button>

<div id="div1">div1 <a href="//google.com">Google</a></div>
<div id="div2">div2 <a href="//stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a></div>
<div id="div3">div3 <a href="//developer.mozilla.org">MDN</a></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

one could `pushState` the ID **selector** of the element to show: `history.pushState({sel: sel}, null);` and retrieve it on page load using `history.state.sel`

```
jQuery( $ => {

    const $divs = $('[id^="div"]');
    const showElement = sel => {
        const $show = $(sel);
        $divs.not($show).addClass('none');
        $show.removeClass('none');
    }

    $('[data-show]').on('click', function () {
        const sel = $(this).data('show');
        history.pushState({sel}, null);
        showElement(sel);
    });

    showElement(history.state.sel || '#div1'); // Init. Fallback to "#div1"

});
```

## Using Storage API - localStorage

Alternatively, you could store the selector string into [window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

<sub>(HTML and CSS same as in the previous example)</sub>

```
jQuery( $ => {

    const $divs = $('[id^="div"]');
    const showElement = sel => {
        const $show = $(sel);
        $divs.not($show).addClass('none');
        $show.removeClass('none');
    }

    $('[data-show]').on('click', function () {
        const sel = $(this).data('show');
        localStorage.sel = sel;
        showElement(sel);
    });

    showElement(localStorage.sel || '#div1'); // Init. Fallback to "#div1"

});
```